# Reference request: Homotopy classification of $S^{n-1}$ fibrations over $S^n$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

It is known to me, that S. Sasao classified in "[Homotopy types of spherical fibre spaces over spheres](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiNzaK4jq7QAhXiLMAKHexhDD8QFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Feuclid.pjm%2F1102912225&usg=AFQjCNGT1_OAJ18GKNwKxQuN8aaJC2RYBg&sig2=PeemkOanEbsrlezOHPvs3Q&bvm=bv.139138859,bs.2,d.bGg)" the homotopy types of $S^q$ fibrations over $S^n$ where $ n > q+1 $. But he ditches the case $q+1=n$. Is there any literature out there which treats this case?

Comment: Isn't this done in [James, I. M.; Whitehead, J. H. C.
The homotopy theory of sphere bundles over spheres. I, II]?

Comment: This is a classification of bundles and not fibrations in general, right?